# What will the code below output to the console and what is the reason?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

This is an interview question and I'm very curious about the answer.

```
var myObject = {
    foo: "bar",
    func: function() {
        var self = this;
        console.log("outer func:  this.foo = " + this.foo);
        console.log("outer func:  self.foo = " + self.foo);
        (function() {
            console.log("inner func:  this.foo = " + this.foo);
            console.log("inner func:  self.foo = " + self.foo);
        }());
    }
};
myObject.func();
```

Comment: Did you try to paste this code into console and run it?

Answer (score 3):

Here's the console output:

```
outer func:  this.foo = bar
outer func:  self.foo = bar
inner func:  this.foo = undefined
inner func:  self.foo = bar
```

This is a demonstration of a [Javascript function closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures), which is a very common question for coding interviews. The outer function has access to the object scope, which is referenced by `this` and assigned to the variable `self`. So both calls to access the property `foo` work as expected,

Then, an inner function is defined inside this function. This inner function does *not* have access to the object scope, but does have access to the scope of it's parent function, where the `self` variable was defined. This is the closure part of the closure so to speak. So when we try and access `self.foo` from the inner function we can access it - as it's been defined in the same lexical scope as the calling function. `this.foo` on the other hand exists in a different scope so cannot be accessed.

Answer (score 3):

Output will be:

```
outer func:  this.foo = bar 
outer func:  self.foo = bar 
inner func:  this.foo = undefined 
inner func:  self.foo = bar
```

Because IIFE(Immediately Invoked Function Expression) will be called in context of global object (window in browsers) so "this" will be global object inside IIFE and when you try to access "this.foo" inside IIFE it will return undefined because there is no property named foo in global object.

```
var xyz = "Hi There"
var myObject = {
    foo: "bar",
    func: function() {
        var self = this;
        console.log("outer func:  this.foo = " + this.foo);
        console.log("outer func:  self.foo = " + self.foo);
        (function() {
            console.log("inner func:  this.foo = " + this.foo);
            console.log("inner func:  this.xyz = " + this.xyz);
            console.log("inner func:  self.foo = " + self.foo);
            console.log("inner func:  this = " + this);
        }());
    }
};
myObject.func();
```

The output for above code will be :

```
outer func:  this.foo = bar 
outer func:  self.foo = bar 
inner func:  this.foo = undefined 
inner func:  this.xyz = Hi There 
inner func:  self.foo = bar
inner func:  this = [object Window]
```

You can learn more about IIFE from https://www.kirupa.com/html5/immediately_invoked_function_expressions_iife.htm

Answer (score 2):

Answer:

```
"outer func:  this.foo = bar"
"outer func:  self.foo = bar"
"inner func:  this.foo = undefined"
"inner func:  self.foo = bar"
```

Reason: **This references the object that is executing the current function.**

- If that function is a *regular function which means it's not part of
  an object* This *reference's the global object which is the window
  object* in browsers and global in node
- If that *function is a part of an object we call that function, a
  method*. So if that function is a method in an object *this
  references that object itself*.

Answer (score 1):

Console logs:

```
outer func:  this.foo = bar
outer func:  self.foo = bar
inner func:  this.foo = undefined
inner func:  self.foo = bar
```

Because in javascript `this` refers to the *caller's context*:

In the call of the `func` function, `this` (the context) refers to the caller object, hence the function has visibility of the caller fields and can access them trough `this`.

In the second function call, `this` will refer to the global object(window in browsers), (the function `func`) that does not have a field called `foo`, hence it will evaluate as `undefined`. Instead, it has access on `self`(due to closure), that's why `self.foo` is accessible.